# parse error unexpected function T_STRING expecting (

Tags: php, syntax-error, parse-error

I can't figure out the problem.

The **error** is `"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'create_lience_file' (T_STRING), expecting '(' in your code on line 2"`.

Don't mind the spelling

```
<?php
$settings = function create_lience_file() {;
$settings['license_key'];
pass_encrypt( $license_key );
$lkeycontent = get_option( 'mlm_license_settings' );
$surlcontent = $license_key = pass_encrypt( site_url(  ) );
$r = file_put_contents( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/mlmLience.txt', $lkeycontent . '|' . $surlcontent );

    if ($r) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call function like below.

```
<?php
function create_lience_file($license_key) {        
    pass_encrypt($license_key);
    $lkeycontent = get_option('mlm_license_settings');
    $surlcontent = $license_key = pass_encrypt(site_url());
    $r = file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__) . '/mlmLience.txt', $lkeycontent . '|' . $surlcontent);
    if ($r) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

$settings = create_lience_file($license_key);
?>
```